# What does "localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself" mean?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, ip, hostname, localhost

I know that the Windows hosts file maps host names to IP addresses. But there is no mapping for *localhost*. Instead it has a comment that says this:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
```

I don't understand this. Where is this "***DNS***" that handles this resolution? Is it a program somewhere in Windows OS? Is it outside of Windows? Does it have a config file? How is this being done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS here refers to the Windows operating system DNS resolver, which is part of the network stack.

Comment: From Microsoft Docs "The resolver is a software component bundled in the Windows 2000 Transmission Control Protocol/Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) stack that communicates with DNS Servers to create and resolve name-resolution queries." So I guess it's a piece of software part of Windows.